# Retrieve particular field from my database

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, attributeerror

I would like to print the dates stored in my **models.py**. However, it seems like Django couldn't access them. Here you can have a look at the relevant pieces of my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

from .models import Aufgabenzettel

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    Aufgaben_items = Aufgabenzettel.objects.all().order_by("-Geplant") #arrange objects in the correct order
    for Aufgabenzettel.Geplant in Aufgaben_items: #run through the loop and...
        print(Aufgabenzettel.Geplant)
        if Aufgabenzettel.Geplant == now: #...search for items in the database where the scheduled time ("Geplant") is equal to the current time
            return render (request, "aufgabenzettel/add.html") #response in any way e.g. by returning the add.html 
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/index.html", {
        "Aufgabenliste":Aufgabenzettel.objects.all(), #currently not used
        "Aufgaben_items":Aufgaben_items
    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Aufgabenzettel(models.Model):
    Aufgabeselbst = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    Datum = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Geplant = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aufgabeselbst}"
```

Whenever I execute the index function it prints the data stored as CharField in *Aufgabenzettel.Aufgabeselbst*. If I change it to `print(Aufgabenzettel.Datum)` it prints as result *<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x00000203BAD2A7C0>*. My goal is to compare `if Aufgabenzettel.Geplant == now` and get a certain response. But if I can't access the correct data, it won't work...

I appreciate your help!

Comment: where are you instantiating your class `Aufgabenzettel`?

Comment: Using `for Aufgabenzettel.Geplant in Aufgaben_items:` makes no sense. You are setting the `Geplant` field of your `Aufgabenzettel` *model*.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your reply. Why doesn‘t it make sense? Could you give some suggestions how to fix it or how to write the for loop properly?

Comment: @mellomax9: because a list of items is not the same as an item and vice versa.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem but why doesn‘t it print the dates stored in my *Geplant* field in the *Aufgabenzettel* database?

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit confused... :/

Comment: @mellomax9: why do you think it should print these? `Aufgaben_items` is a `QuerySet` (a collection) of `Aufgaben` objects, not of date(time)s.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem What can I do to compare the dates stored in my database and compare them with the current time? ( *if Aufgabenzettel.Geplant == now* ?)